# filling up a container in a nonconsecutive order

Tags: python, list, initialization

I'm reading a file where each line contains number from 1 to x and some relevant string I need to save.

I wanted to read the number eg. index and the string and then save this string in a list as an element with an index that i read.

```
fread = open("sample.txt", "r")
lines = fread.readlines()
fread.close()

data = []
for line in lines:
  temp = line.split("\t")
  data[int(temp[0])] = temp[1]
```

But I get `IndexError: list index out of range`

What is the most appropriate solution for my problem?

Comment: You'd have to pre-size the list; you cannot treat it as a sparse list and just assign to any non-existing index. You can do that with a dictionary instead perhaps.

Comment: your second sentence is too complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign to non-existing indexes. Either pre-size the list:

```
data = [None] * some_size
```

or use a dictionary:

```
data = {}
for line in lines:
    elems = line.split("\t")
    data[int(elems[0])] = elems[1]
```

then later turn that into a list perhaps:

```
data = [data.get(i, None) for i in range(max(data))]
```

This'll build a list with enough elements to store all entries at the indices you read from the file, plus `None` values for any indices not present in the file.

Comment: it actually doesn't matter which container(atleast for now), thanks, didn't know about dictionaries :)

Comment: what if i want to increment data? `++data[int(elems[0])]` wont work

Comment: @TheGuyWithStreetCred: Python has no `++` operator. Use `data[int(elems[0])] += 1`.

Comment: @TheGuyWithStreetCred: you may want to look at [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) there though; `data = defaultdict(int)` then `data[int(elements[0])] += 1` will work when the index isn't yet there (it'll insert a 0 for you).